# Email from Java program to drafts folder of Outlook Enterprise email account

Tags: java, email, outlook, enterprise

I've been given the task of overhauling a program that is written in Java, which, among many other things, generates one or more emails that have to be reviewed by the user before being sent (because the email is part of a product delivery package, and everything that goes out to clients must be reviewed in a QA process before being sent).

Previously the program was written such that the email portion interacted with Lotus Notes. The company no longer uses Lotus Notes and I know nothing about Lotus Notes.

Presently we use Microsoft Outlook with Enterprise email accounts.

My pie-in-the-sky dream for the email module is to have it generate an email and drop that email directly into the Outlook drafts folder of the user, ready to send. Unfortunately, I don't know if that's possible especially given that the email folders are all synched with an Enterprise server.

If anyone could point me in the right direction for further research, I would appreciate it. My own Google search sessions have led me on many wild tangents but produced no real useable information. If you choose to reply with any information, please bear in mind that I am a relatively new and inexperienced programmer who is doing a lot of post-college stumbling-and-learning.

Thank you in advance for any answers and for any patience with my low experience level.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the POI libraries for Java.  They are ways of interfacing with MS Office applications through Java. I believe you could simply create a .msg file then place that file in the drafts folder and have it sync with the enterprise exchange server.

http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Exchange WebServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx)

An [Send email](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa566468%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) example

The IMAP protocol could be another option.

Answer (score 0):

javax.mail.Message contains a setFlag method to mark the message as a draft a message. so you can create a mail message but mark it as draft to store in the drafts folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use Outlook Object Model. JACOB shoud let you do that from Java.
Something like the following (VB script):

set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set NS = App.GetNamespace("MAPI")
NS.Logon
set Msg = App.CreateItem(0)
Msg.Subject = "test subject"
Msg.Body = "test body"
Msg.Display *'or call Msg.Save to just save the message*